# Blender Guru Photorealistic Puddles Tutorial-How to use the water puddle node group

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor

I loved the photorealistic puddles tutorial, i downloaded the re-usable node group prepared by Blender Guru and connected the approprite/respective sockets to the node group but the wetness slider dosent affect my material as on the tutorial but if i copy my mesh (plane) into the original file sent by Bledner Gruru, the surface getas affected appropriatley. Am i missing something? Any help would be appreciated!! NB. Using Blender 3.4.1 and Blender 3.5

Here is the link to the tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TxYVMw94FXE&ab_channel=BlenderGuru

Below is a screen shot of my node setup after appending the node group form Blender Guru's file( link is further down below)

[image]

Blender Guru's file which can be downloded from linked here below:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/sndkap18nd7gwtn/BlenderGuru_PuddlesNodeGroup.blend?dl=0

Am not sure if i missed as step or something need to be done to the respective mesh to get the puddles to show. I would really appreaciate the help.

I have also updated the information to incluse a preview of the material i am experiemnting with.... See below
[image]

Here is the link to my blend file as well incase someone would like to have a look to see where am going wrong!I have embedded all the resources/textures i used in the test file

https://www.dropbox.com/s/vi1s0fynkuqbc5e/puddles%20test.blend?dl=0

Comment: Well, since I have no idea what textures you are using etc. it's hard to tell from the screenshot what is wrong there. Just a quick question: is there a specific reason you plug a Displacement vector output into the Height input of the node group which expects a float value? Andrew plugs a float value in there in his tutorial.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann - I think recal saing we can use the dispalcement map as opposed to using a value. I could be wrong though

Comment: Yeah, but the map is a greyscale image which will be interpreted as float values. The map is what you plugged into the Displacement node, it's not the output of that node. I guess Blender will make something of it, but probably the greyscale map will give better results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When looking inside the nodegroup with <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd> on Blender 3.4 we can see a lot of red "Undefined" nodes:

[image]

That means the nodegroup was made using nodes that don't exist anymore.

At a glance, I guess it is mostly Mix RGB nodes that got replaced by the Mix node. You could just rewatch the tutorial and replace the nodes you see by the mix node with the right settings.

---

[At 21:32](https://youtu.be/TxYVMw94FXE?t=1292) the tutorial shows how to set up the vertex painting to be able to paint the area of effect. The node group assumes the name of the Color Attribute created by switching into vertex paint mode will be `Col`.

Make sure you created that color attribute, with the right name, and painted some white somewhere on your mesh. Otherwise, it won't work at all.

Comment: Strange, I just recently had a different question here where there was the same problem with the old _MixRGB_ nodes. However when I opened this file and looked into the group, nothing showed red in my Blender (3.4.1).

Comment: AFAIK blender is supposed to convert the nodes, but sometimes it doesn't for some reason. But replacing the nodes by hand also works.

Comment: @L0Lock - Please all my nodes do not appear red! Could you perhaps try an updated version to see if your results change and if you can get it to work!

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann- Have you had any success getting the sample file i created to work with the pudddles nodes?

Comment: have you set up your color attribute with the right name and painted some white in it?

Comment: @L0Lock - That was it, i refeered back to the videoas you indicated in your edited answer. I set up vertex painting and renamed the colour attribute to Col and painted a white and voila!! it working... Thank you for the help. Much apprecaited!